# Let's live in hope. Let's live on hope. Let's live with hope

Tags: prepositions

Let's live in hope. 
Let's live on hope. 
Let's live with hope.

Which preposition should be put ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference in meaning between prepositions.

> To live ***in*** hope = Hope surrounds us like a house, we feel comfort that comes from it.
>   To live ***on*** hope = Hope is like the fuel or food for us, it sustains us.
>   To live ***with*** hope = Hope lives alongside us, it is part of our life, like a dear family member.

So, it depends on how you want your statement to be interpreted.